# Update value of variable

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I'm doing a Makefile and I have a problem to update the value of a variable...

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Makefile 

IMPORT_PATH := github.com/... 
CHECK := 0

.PHONY: install 
install: 
        $Q printf "\\nLet's install..."
        $Q if grep -q \!string "$(DIR)" ; then CHECK = $($CHECK + 1) ; fi
        $Q printf "done!"
```

I want if the condition is good, update the value of CHECK from 0 to 1, but I don't know how can I do this, any suggestion?

Comment: `CHECK=$((CHECK+1))` or `((CHECK += 1))` without space around `=`

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know if it's my version of gmake but I have a lot of problems with the syntax. With your solution: `Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: as it is in a makefile maybe you have to use double $ : `CHECK=$$((CHECK+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty arises from modifying Makefile variables with shell commands

```
IMPORT_PATH := github.com/... 
CHECK := 0

.PHONY: install 
install: 
    $Q printf "\\nLet's install..."
    $(eval CHECK := $(shell if grep -q \!string "$(DIR)" ; then echo $$(( $(CHECK) +1)) ; else echo $(CHECK) fi) )
    $Q printf "done!"
```

For example to increment CHECK Makefile variable

```
    $(eval CHECK := $(shell echo $$(( $(CHECK) + 1 )) ) )
```

Comment: Super! It works! Thank you so much @nahuel-fouilleul